# LLamada a funciones anidada en STRUCT dentro de una CLASE

Tags: c++, lista, estructuras-de-datos, clase, constructor

Tengo esta implementación de una clase que maneja listas enlazadas.

El tema es que estoy usando funciones *primitivas* en el struct que uso dentro de la clase, sin embargo no tengo mucho conocimiento de ello, y no se como invocar las funciones. Aquí reproduzco mi problema. muchas gracias

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class linkedList
{
private:

    struct node
    {
        char valor;
        node *next;
        node( char nuevoValor, node * nuevoNext)
         : valor( nuevoValor ), next( nuevoNext )
         {   }
         // prinmitivos
         static node * stringALista(const char *s); // para el constructor
    };

    node *head;

public:
    explicit linkedList( const char * s = "");
    //linkedList( const linkedList & s );

};


int main()
{
    linkedList list1 ("hola mundo");
}

linkedList::linkedList(const char *s)
{
    // como llamar a la funcion stringALista???
}

// aquí   ↓ dice 45 11  Error] expected unqualified-id before '.' token
linkedList.node * linkedList::stringALista(const char *s)
{
    node * aux = NULL;
    node * cur = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    while ( ( s + i * sizeof(char)) != '\0' )
    {

        if ( cur == NULL)
        {
            cur = new node;
            cur->valor = &s;
            cur->next = NULL
            aux = cur;
        }
        else 
        {
            while (cur->next != NULL) 
                cur = cur->next;
            cur->next = new node;
            cur->next->valor = &s;
            cur->next->next = NULL;
        }

    }
    return aux;
}
```

Lo que quiero es poder usar la función de la estructura en la clase linkedList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
linkedList.node * linkedList::stringALista(
```

`node` es una estructura anidada que se encuentra dentro de la clase `linkedList`. El  operador `.` se usa para acceder a funcionalidad propia de una instancia concreta de la clase y este no es el caso... la estructura `node` no pertenece a una instancia de `linkedList`, luego el operador a utilizar es `::`. Además, el método `stringALista` pertenece a la clase `node`, luego es necesario indicar ese ámbito también:

```
linkedList::node * linkedList::node::stringALista(
```

Por otro lado esto está mal:

```
while ( ( s + i * sizeof(char)) != '\0' )
```

`s` es un puntero y el compilador es lo suficientemente inteligente como para aplicar desplazamientos adecuados a dicho puntero. Así:

```
char* ptr1 = 0;
std::cout << (void*)(ptr1+1); // imprime 1

int* ptr2 = 0;
std::cout << (void*)(ptr2+1); // imprime 4
```

En la aritmética de punteros no debes tener en cuenta el tamaño de cada registro del puntero. Esa es una responsabilidad del compilador. Por tanto, esa línea debería lucir más bien así:

```
while ( ( s + i ) != '\0' ) // opción 1

while ( s[i] != '\0' ) // opción 2
```

En cualquier caso fíjate que no estás incrementando el valor de `i` por lo que el bucle se repetirá​ indefinidamente.

Para bucles con un rango definido suele ser más práctico y limpio un bucle `for`

```
for( int i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
```

Además, el contenido del bucle tiene ciertos problemas. Si te fijas verás que el bucle va a crear tantos nodos como caracteres tenga la cadena `s` y **en cada nodo intentas almacenar un puntero a la cadena**, cuando lo que pretendes es almacenar cada caracter individual. El bucle debería quedar más bien así:

```
for( int i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++ )
{
  if ( cur == NULL)
  {
    cur = new node(s[i],0);
    aux = cur;
  }
  else 
  {
    cur->next = new node(s[i],0);
    cur = cur->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: Totalmente acertado,en casi todo, excepto en que si, en realidad si quiero crear tantos nodos como caracteres tiene la cadena. 

Muchas gracias

Comment: En realidad la correcta implementación es así `linkedList::node* linkedList::node::stringALista(const char *s)`

Comment: @JacoboCórdova por las mañanas suelo revisar SO desde el móvil mientras desayuno. Se ve que el corrector se ha cargado el asterisco y no me he dado cuenta. Ahora desde el pc le doy una pasada a la respuesta por si tiene más gazapos. Gracias

Comment: jeje.. el tema no es el asterisco.. el tema es que strigALista no es un miembro de LinkedList sino de node. por eso para poder invocarla es necesario decirle linkedlist:: luego node:: y entonces stringALista ;) espero tu edicion. ;)

Comment: @JacoboCórdova cierto. Ese detalle se me pasó por alto. a veces pienso que debería dejar de consultar la web desde el móvil...

Comment: No, por favor, para esos detalles estamos nosotros jajaja

Comment: @JacoboCórdova responder desde el móvil tiene su hándicap: no puedes compilar, si copias código éste se pega sin saltos de línea, escribir código es más engorroso, el corrector te juega malas pasadas... pero no se, tiene su gracia asumir el riesgo de responder a pelo jejejeje